# Difference between initializing char* and int* with an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures

Can someone explain this code snippet to me?

```c
int main(void) {
    // segment 1
    char *d = "sadwad";
    printf("%s", d);
    
    // segment 2
    int *d = {32,454,652,12};
    printf("%d",d[0]);
}
```

After some searching, I saw that when I declare `char *d = "sadwad"` that means that the pointer is pointer to the first `char` in the string and the first points to the second and so on.
Do I understand this correctly?

My questions here:

1. Why do we use `d` without the indirection operator `*`; I think that should print the reference of the first char in my point of view.
2. Why does segment 2 blow up? I think it works the same as `char *d = "sadwad"` cause both are arrays, and the the line `printf("%d",d[0]);` is equal to `printf("%c", d[0]);`

Comment: *"the first point to the second and so on"* - What source claimed that? That's completely wrong, elements of an array (which a "string" really is) do not implicitly point to other elements of the array

Comment: 1) The type `%s` expects is `char*`.  Dereferencing gives you just `char`.  What do you mean by "blow up?"

Comment: The code also fails to compile because you're trying to define two different variables named `d` in the same function

Comment: I think you should read the chapter dealing with pointers and the3 one dealing with arrays in your learning material.

Comment: Segment 1: `d` points to the string literal "sadwad". The `%s` format specifier prints the string pointed by the the corresponding parameter (`d` in this case).

Comment: Segment 2: this doesn't compile and makes no sense. You probably wanted `int f[] = {32,454,652,12}; printf("%d", f[0]);`. This would print the first element of the `f` array.

Comment: You have an unclean [mre], which however can be split into two separate MREs. Each of them uses `printf()` according to its specification. Things and phrases I do not get in your question and which you should probably clarify. a) see comment by UnholySheep b) "that should print the reference of the first char", no idea what you mean by "the reference of ...", consider giving an example c) "blow up"; compiler error or runtime error or unexpected output or .... ?

Comment: d) "cause they are arrays", they are not, arrays and pointers are not the same though sometimes used confusingly similarily, you found an example of where they are not, i.e. for printf

Comment: The closest C gets to the notion of a "string", is "null-terminated sequence of characters, referenced by a pointer to the first char" is not the same as an array of char. Tricky is the use of "string literals" i.e. something like `"abc"`, which for example does not allow to be modified and fiendishly hindes a fourth char, the `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: It is probably best to initialize an array variable like `int f[] = {32,454,652,12};`. If you really want a pointer to an unnamed array, you could use a *compound literal* like this: `int *f = (int[]){32,454,652,12};` (supported by C99 and later) but you would not be able to compute the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Your code is invalid C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that's mean that the pointer is point to the first char in the string

More importantly, the string literal `"sadwad"` is stored like an array in a read-only part of the memory. So you can't write to it. Therefore correct use is

```
const char *d = "sadwad";
```

Or if you wish to have a local read/write copy of the read-only string literal, don't use a pointer but a proper array:

```
char d[] = "sadwad";
```

---

> Why we use d without de-reference operator *

Because `printf` family of functions have very poor conception of types - they rely on the programmer entering the correct format string to tell the function what to expect. In case of `%c` it would expect a character and then you'd have to pass a de-referenced `*d` in order to print the first character. But in case of `%s` it actually expects a character pointer to a null terminated string, that's just how `%s` works. So no need to de-reference.

---

> `int *d = {32,454,652,12};`

This will crash because this is invalid C. It does not do what you think. The root of your problems here is an incorrectly configured compiler, causing you to troubleshoot bugs that the compiler has already found. Check out [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) to avoid wasting time on similar things in the future.

Somewhat advanced topic:
In order to assign a pointer to an array of integers, you would have to use a *compound literal*:

```
int *e = (int[]){32,454,652,12};
```

This is equivalent to using a named array in the same manner:

```
int arr[] = {32,454,652,12};
int *e = arr;
```

In both cases the scope of the array is that of the surrounding `{}` and it will become invalid at the next `}`.

---

> Why the segment 2 blow up?

Definitely advanced topic. If you must know, then since you had gcc or similar compiler in lax mode, it gave 2 warnings but spat out an executable regardless. The warnings were:

> `warning: initialization of 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast`
> `warning: excess elements in scalar initializer`

The first warning means that the compiler saw that you tried to initialize a pointer, and as a non-standard C extension it allowed this to slip. The compiler treated the first initializer `32` as the *memory address* to initialize the pointer to. Oops. Nothing good will likely come from de-referencing address 32.

The second warning is some serious C language gibberish. Scalar means "single variable", such as a plain `int` or a pointer. You *are* actually allowed to initialize such variables like `int x = { 123 };`, though the braces don't have any function. "Excess elements" means that it only grabbed the first initializer `32` and then discarded the rest of them.

Comment: I have a comment on this part:
In case of %c it would expect a character and then you'd have to pass a de-referenced *d

Also if you pass `d[0]` it will print the character so how about that?

Comment: @AbdalrahmanMaher `d[n]` is by definition 100% equivalent to `*(d + n)`.

Answer (score 0):

> when I declare char *d = "sadwad" that means that the pointer is pointer to the first char in the string and the first points to the second and so on

No, you're describing a linked list. `d` points to the array, and since the first character in the array is the very beginning of the array, `d` happens also to point to the first character. Arrays in C are just a contiguous list of values, so the second character immediately follows the first, and so on.

> Why do we use d without the indirection operator *; I think that should print the reference of the first char in my point of view.

If you mean in the first `printf()` statement, it's because the format specifier `%s` expects the associated value to be a string, i.e. a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters.

> Why does segment 2 blow up?

Because a variable named `d` has already been declared in the same scope. Choose a different name for your second array and you'll be fine.